# Could not determine GDB version using command: sudo /usr/local/bin/gdb --version

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, terminal, eclipse

Eclipse (Mars) version (C programming language):
Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
eclipse.buildId=4.5.0.I20150603-2000

MacOS version:
OS X Yosemite 10.10.3
HW: MacbookPro 15" (mid-2015) Retina

Problem:
Debug action causes following error message ("111" is both Project Name, and source 111.c file as well):

window title: "Problem Occurred"
Error message: 
'Launching 111' has encountered a problem. 
Could not determine GDB version using command: sudo /usr/local/bin/gdb --version
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

As far as I understand - that GBD module was removed from MacOS X, so I probably need to install manually one. 
I am newcomer in Mac, and trying installing upon different forums - I didn't succeed yet.

Probably, there maybe changes required as well in:

> Debug Configurations (Run->Debug Configuration->"Debugger" tab). 
>   Or/and as well in:
>   Eclipse -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Debug -> GDB

Please answer me - who installed recently by him-/her- self. Since old (more than year from now) forums may describe other case compared to problem I need to solve.

Please provide exact steps how to manage.

Comment: Modern OSX and Xcode do not provide gcc or gdb they provide clang and lldb . You might try lldb-mi https://www.codeplay.com/portal/lldb-mi-driver---part-1-introduction

Answer (score 1):

## Install with MacPorts

1. Install Xcode and [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/install.php), if not already installed.
2. Now install the Apple GCC and GDB from MacPorts:

   $ sudo port install gdb-apple
   $ sudo port install apple-gcc42

## Install with Homebrew

1. Install Xcode and [Homebrew](http://brew.sh), if not already installed.
2. Now install GDB from Homebrew:

   $ brew tap homebrew/dupes
   $ brew install gdb

Source: http://ntraft.com/installing-gdb-on-os-x-mavericks/

Comment: And what configuration changes are required in Eclipse IDE itself - to let it know to refer properly to newly this added installation ? Do I need both MacPorts and Homebrew - or they do similar job and any of them is enough ? And what about LLDB which as I understand replaces in MacOS X GDB - is it required as well ? Can't I just install GDB for most minimal changes, like latest Eclipse asks for ? Sorry for many questions - I just spend much time without deeply understand what all this modules stand for. And apple support can't help me till now :(

Comment: You probably won't have to change anything. If eclipse doesn't see it, go to Preferences->C/C++->Debug->GDB and browse GDB Debugger at /usr/local/bin/gdb. You do not have to install both. I recommend [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) package manager since it's easier to install and use. I don't think eclipse needs LLDB (not positive though).

Comment: I performed both install with "MacPorts" and "Homebrew" steps above. But strange behaviour I see is - after closing and reopening Eclipse (without installing or removing any installation in between), it gives again same error message: 'Launching 111' has encountered a problem. Could not determine GDB version using command: sudo /usr/local/bin/gdb --version sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified". How can I make debugger stable - to work (without error) forever ? Is there any configuration in Eclipse required as well ? Why it can be such unstable ? Please provide steps to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to installing from macports / homebrew, on Yosemite you also need to sign the gdb binary. See http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin .

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! We generally try and avoid link-only answers, since your answer will instantly lose all helpfulness if the link ever disappears. Could you please edit your answer to add some of the details from the site? Thanks!